# Sort dates order between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two dates as a parameters and list of current dates and same periods of previous years . I need partition list between parameters. Logic is if date between '20171201' AND '20180301' then 1, if date between '20161201' and '20170301' then 2 and so on. But count of periods in list not static, like:

```
DECLARE @DateEnd DATE = '20180331'
  , @DateBeg DATE = '20171201'

DECLARE @tab TABLE([date] DATE)
INSERT INTO @tab ([date])
VALUES('2014-12-01')
, ('2015-01-01')
, ('2015-02-01')
, ('2015-03-01')
, ('2015-12-01')
, ('2016-01-01')
, ('2016-02-01')
, ('2016-03-01')
, ('2016-12-01')
, ('2017-01-01')
, ('2017-02-01')
, ('2017-03-01')
, ('2017-12-01')
, ('2018-01-01')
, ('2018-02-01')
, ('2018-03-01')
```

Result should be

```
Date        Cnt
2014-12-01  4
2015-01-01  4
2015-02-01  4
2015-03-01  4
2015-12-01  3
2016-01-01  3
2016-02-01  3
2016-03-01  3
2016-12-01  2
2017-01-01  2
2017-02-01  2
2017-03-01  2
2017-12-01  1
2018-01-01  1
2018-02-01  1
2018-03-01  1
```

Comment: what is the logic for the `Cnt` ?

Comment: Logic is if date between '20171201' AND '20180301' then 1, if date between '20161201' and '20170301' then 2 and so on. But count of periods in list not static

Comment: what do you mean "count of periods in list not static"?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: What if you had dates outside that range? If your table would contain `2017-10-20`, what value should it get in the `cnt` column at the result?

Answer (score 2):

use `CASE WHEN` satetement to check for the date and return the value accordingly

```
select  *, 
        Cnt = CASE 
              WHEN date BETWEEN '20171201' AND '20180331' THEN 1
              WHEN date BETWEEN '20161201' AND '20170331' THEN 2            
              WHEN date BETWEEN '20151201' AND '20160331' THEN 3
              WHEN date BETWEEN '20141201' AND '20150331' THEN 4            
              END
from    @tab
```

EDIT :

Or maybe this is what you want ?

this will gives you the begining of the financial year

```
dateadd(month, - month(date) % 12, date)
```

your `Cnt` is no of years between the financial year and today ?

```
select  *, 
        Cnt = datediff(year, dateadd(month, - month(date) % 12, date), getdate())
from    @tab
```

Comment: I can't use it, because list of period isn't static

Comment: then how is the date related to the `period` and `cnt` ?

Answer (score 0):

Using dateadd() within a case expression should enable this:

```
select
  datecol
, case when datecol between @DateBeg and @DateEnd then 1 
       when datecol between dateadd(year,-1,@DateBeg) and dateadd(year,-1,@DateEnd) then 2
       when datecol between dateadd(year,-2,@DateBeg) and dateadd(year,-2,@DateEnd) then 3
       when datecol between dateadd(year,-3,@DateBeg) and dateadd(year,-3,@DateEnd) then 4
  end
from @tab
```

also see: http://rextester.com/BTF82190